# Function to find average for array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Did I implement `float overallavg(float* matrix, int rows, int cols)`correctly? I think I didn't. I'm trying to return the average value of the elements of the array pointed to by matrix. Should I call the other two functions into the overall one and then divide by the total number elements in the array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *readMatrix(int rows, int cols);
float *rowavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols);
float *colavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols);
float overallavg(float* matrix, int rows, int cols);
void printavg(float *matrix, float *rowAve, float *colAve, float overallAve, int rows, int cols);

#define MAX_DIM 10

int main(void)
{
  int done = 0;
  int rows, cols;
  float *dataMatrix;
  float *rowAveVector;
  float *colAveVector;
  float overallAve;

  while (!done)
  {
    // Prompt user to enter row and column dimensions of matrix (must be > 0)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter row dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
        scanf("%d", &rows);

    } while(rows <= 0 || rows > MAX_DIM);
    do
    {
        printf("Enter column dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
        scanf("%d", &cols);
    } while(cols <= 0 || cols > MAX_DIM);

    dataMatrix = readMatrix(rows, cols);
    if (dataMatrix == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Program terminated due to dynamic memory allocation failure\n");
        return (0);
    }


    rowAveVector = rowAverage(dataMatrix, rows, cols);
    colAveVector = colAverage(dataMatrix, rows, cols);
    if(rowAveVector == NULL || colAveVector == NULL)
    {
     printf("malloc failed.  Terminating program\n");
     return (0);
    }
    overallAve = overallAverage(dataMatrix, rows, cols);

    //Print Averages
    printAverages(dataMatrix, rowAveVector, colAveVector, overallAve, rows, cols);

    free(dataMatrix);
    free(rowAveVector);
    free(colAveVector);

    //Check if user wants to enter a new matrix
    printf("Enter 0 to continue with a new matrix\n");
    printf("Enter any other number to terminate the program: ");
    scanf("%d", &done);
  }
  //That's it, we are done
  return (0);
}

float *readMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int elements=0;
    float *m=malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));
    if (m==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            elements = i*cols+j;
            scanf("%f", &m[elements]);
        }
    }
    return m;
}

float *readMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int elements=0;
    float *m=malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));
    if (m==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            elements = i*cols+j;
            scanf("%f", &m[elements]);
        }
    }
    return m;
}


float *rowavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  float mean=0;
  float *Average_array=malloc(rows*sizeof(float));
  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[i*cols+j];
      }
      Average_array[i]=(float)(mean/cols);
  }
  return Average_array;
}


float *colavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  float mean=0;
  float *Average_array=malloc(cols*sizeof(float));
  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for (i=0;i<cols;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[j*cols+i];
      }
      Average_array[i]=(float)(mean/rows);
  }
  return Average_array;
}

float overallavg(float* matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  float mean_1=0;
  float mean_2=0;
  float avg=0;
  float elements=0;
  float sum=0;
  elements=rows*cols;
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
          mean_1+=matrix[i*rows+j];
      }
  }
  for (i=0;i<cols;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
      {
          mean_2+=matrix[j*cols+i];
      }
  }
  sum=mean_1+mean_2;
  avg=sum/elements-1;
}
```

Comment: when initializing a `float` variable to zero, the correct statement is: `float value = 0.0f;`  Not `float value = 0;`

Comment: the function `malloc()` is expecting its' parameter to be 'long unsigned int` (I.E. `size_t`)  however, `rows` and `cols` are `int`, (and we can expect that those values will never be negative)  Suggest when passing `cols` and `rows` to use the `size_t` type rather than the `int` type

Comment: regarding lines like this one: `Average_array[i] = (float)(mean/cols);`  Will cause the compiler to raise a warning message.  Suggest `Average_array[i] = (mean/(float)cols);`

Comment: since the passed parameters `rows` and `cols` should be of type `size_t`, so should the loop counters `j` and `i` and `elements`

Comment: the function `overallavg()` is declared to return a `float`, but there is no return statement at the end of the function.   There is a `return NULL;` statement at the beginning of the function, but NULL is NOT a `float`.  So that function needs re-written.

Comment: in the function: `overallavg()`, the variable `avg` is set but never used.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when posting code, always include the `#include` statements so we do not have to guess as to what the actual code has included.

Comment: @user3629249 hey i just updated the code with main and everything else

Comment: @user3629249, while an initialization to `0.0f` is correct and provides a *type suffix*, there is no penalty for initializing with `0.0` and the only miniscule penalty for initializing with `0` is the *internal type conversion*. While your statement is correct, it is good to try and help new programmers understand why.

Comment: When i run theres no errors so that should be good

Comment: the 'edited' / 'updated' posted code still does not cleanly compile,  Strongly suggest enabling all compiler warnings, then fix those warnings.  Ignore those warnings at your peril,  One of the warnings is about one of the functions has a declared return type of `float *`,but the body of the function, at best, only returns a NULL.  If the rest of the code were to try to access the float value pointed to by that NULL, then the program would crash with a segment fault.  I.E. just because it says 'warning' in the compiler message doesn't mean it can be ignored

Comment: the `MAX_DIM` is an unnecessary constraint on the code logic.  Such restraint is not justified in the introduction to the question and just results in complications within the actual code.  Also, this text: `(must be between 1 and %d)` says the allowed values are: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  Perhaps you meant: `(must be in the range 1...%d)`

Answer (score 1):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. contains the needed `#include` statements

Note: this line:

```
avg=sum/elements-1;
```

will not calculate the average of all the elements but rather a somewhat larger value because the total number of elements is being decremented by 1

Suggestion, in the function: `overallavg()`  do not calculate separate 'mean' values, rather simply step through the whole array summing each element, then divide by the total number of elements

Suggestion, use an indent width of 4 spaces, as that is easily visible, even with a variable width font.  2 spaces with a variable width font just looks like the indented row is indented about 1/2 the width of a char. I.E. barely visible and very messy looking.  (code is read many many times so should be written to be very easy to read.

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf() scanf()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free()

float *readMatrix( size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    //int i=0;
    //int j=0;
    size_t elements=0;

    float *m=malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));

    if (m==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");

    for (size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for ( size_t j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            elements = i*cols+j;
            scanf("%f", &m[elements]);
        }
    }

    return m;
}


float *rowavg(float *matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }

  //int i=0;
  //int j=0;
  float mean=0;

  float *Average_array=malloc(rows*sizeof(float));

  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }

  for ( size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
      for ( size_t j=0; j<cols; j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[i*cols+j];
      }
      Average_array[i] = (mean/(float)cols);
  }

  return Average_array;
}


float *colavg(float *matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }

  //int i=0;
  //int j=0;
  float mean=0;

  float *Average_array = malloc( cols*sizeof(float) );

  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }

  for ( size_t i=0; i<cols; i++)
  {
      for (size_t j=0; j<rows; j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[j*cols+i];
      }
      Average_array[i] = (mean/(float)rows);
  }
  return Average_array;
}



float overallavg(float* matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    #if 0
    if (matrix==NULL)
    {
      return NULL;
    }
    #endif

  //int i=0;
  //int j=0;
  float mean_1=0;
  float mean_2=0;
  float avg=0;
  float elements=0;
  float sum=0;

  elements= (float)rows* (float)cols;

  for ( size_t i=0;i<rows;i++)
  {
      for ( size_t j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
          mean_1+=matrix[i*rows+j];
      }
  }

  for ( size_t i=0; i<cols; i++)
  {
      for ( size_t j=0; j<rows ;j++)
      {
          mean_2+=matrix[j*cols+i];
      }
  }

  sum=mean_1+mean_2;
  avg=sum/elements-1;

  return avg;
}
```

Comment: Note: in the function: `overallavg()`  every element is being counted twice, once of the row 'mean' and again for the 'column' mean.  So the final result will not be correct.

Comment: @nm10563,    I wrote my answer before you applied an edit to the question.  BTW: when editing a question after comments, answers, etc have been posted, ADD additional text/code.  Do not modify the original question contents, because then the comments/answers will (often, as in this case) not make sense.